# Thresholed sum in python

Tags: python, algorithm

A friend of mine was asked the following at a job interview for junior python dev.

> A building has one elevator. Employees wait in an ordered line to take the lift up. The elevator has a maximum mass capacity. How many trips is the elevator going to do? The masses of the passengers are provided in an (ordered) list.

The following C-style loop will do the job, true, but **isn't there a concise (hopefully a one-liner) for such a canonical problem?**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

MAX_MASS = 280  # kg

def how_many(masses):
    trips = 0
    total_mass = 0
    for m in masses:
        # Elevator full - depart.
        if total_mass + m > MAX_MASS:
            trips = trips + 1
            total_mass = 0

        total_mass = total_mass + m

    # Not full but some passagers remain.
    if total_mass > 0:
        trips = trips + 1

    return trips


if __name__ == '__main__':
    passangers = [19, 22, 34, 33, 82, 91, 77, 31, 87]
    trips = how_many(passangers)
    print(trips)
```

Comment: Can you provide some code or your approach to this problem?

Comment: @Cardstdani thanks for the comment! I will write and post it right away.

Comment: Are the passengers to be lifted in their order of waiting?

Comment: @user2390182 yes. Also there are no passengers from other floors.

Comment: You're missing an `else` or a `continue` after the the first `if`

Comment: You do have `itertools.accumulate`. But that in itself is not such a great help as it needs to reset for every new trip.

Comment: @joao no I am not. My code says "else ... do nothing".

Comment: How does your C++ solution look like?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could abuse [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html).

```
from textwrap import wrap

def how_many(masses):
    return len(wrap(' '.join('.' * (m-1) for m in masses), MAX_MASS-1))
```

(Might produce a wrong result when there's an employee with mass 1 kg, but that seems rather unlikely.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertoosl.accumulate` to shorten this a bit:

```
from itertools import accumulate as acc

def trips(masses, mm):
    i = res = 0
    while i < len(masses):
        res += 1
        i = next((i for i, a in enumerate(acc(masses[i:]), i) if a > mm), len(masses))
    return res
```

Algorithmically, the slices are a bother (`O(K)` in time and space), but you can replace `masses[i:]` with `islice(masses, i, None)`.

If you allow recursion, you can get this down to:

```
def trips(masses, mm):
    if not (n := len(masses)):
        return 0
    return 1 + trips(masses[next((i for i, a in enumerate(acc(masses)) if a > mm), n):], mm)

trips([19, 22, 34, 33, 82, 91, 77, 31, 87], 280)
# 3
```

Some docs:

- [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)
- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)
- [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: What's the time complexity when you do use `islice(masses, i, None)`?

Comment: It should be linear then. All elements are visited only once for the accumulation.

Comment: But `next(islice(masses, i, None))` isn't `O(1)` but `Θ(i)`, since every `islice` first iterates over the first `i` elements to get to where you want to start from. So overall I think the time complexity remains the same, i.e. `O(n²)`.

Comment: I tried with `masses = [1] * 10000; mm = 1`, your first solution and its `islice` variant were both equally slow. About 190 times slower than the OP's original, 198 ms vs their 1.04 ms. A version with `acc(masses[j] for j in range(i, n))` was "only" 17 times slower than theirs. (Your recursive version errored with too deep recursion).

Comment: @KellyBundy You are right, of course. My initial approach was to turn the list into an iterator, but the lookahead issue makes for some ugly code there. Kinda weird though, because it should be easy for `islice` to leverage the sequence protocol (using `__getitem__` instead of `__iter__`) where possible.

Comment: Using the sequence protocol would be *terrible* for example for `deque`, though, since that takes linear time for `__getitem__`. So it would have to be the user's explicit choice to use that. I saw a [PEP draft](https://github.com/PythonCHB/islice-pep/blob/master/pep-xxx-islice.rst) for something that would make this efficient, though this use case isn't even on its list of advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

def how_many(masses, MAX_MASS):
    def my_func(acc, m):
        trips, tmp = acc
        return (trips + 1, m) if tmp + m > MAX_MASS else (trips, tmp + m)

    return reduce(my_func, masses, (1, 0))[0]
```

The call to `reduce` returns a tuple, so we take the first element which is the number of trips.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`split_before`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_before) from module `more_itertools` to split when the mass becomes too much; and using [`ilen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.ilen) from the same module to count the splits.

```py
from more_itertools import split_before, ilen

def count_trips(seq, max_mass):
    def acc(x):
        if acc.mass + x <= max_mass:
            acc.mass += x
            return False
        else:
            acc.mass = x
            return True
    acc.mass = 0
    return ilen(split_before(seq, acc))

print(count_trips([19, 22, 34, 33, 82, 91, 77, 31, 87], 280))
# 3   ( [[19, 22, 34, 33, 82], [91, 77, 31], [87]] )
```